# Shading the area between arcs with a rainbow

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, arc

I am trying to shade areas between arcs in a rainbow fashion - and I want to be able to control if the red end is the lower end or at the upper one.  MEW:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);    % center c1
  \foreach \ini/\fin/\rad in {40/50/    3.0,
                             120/160/   3.3,
                              80/42/    3.6,  %backwards
                             320/275/   3.9,  %backwards
                             180/223/   4.2,
                             265/ 285/  4.5}
 {  \draw[fill=green]
 ($(c1) + (\ini:\rad)$) arc (\ini:\fin:\rad)  
  --  ($(c1) + (\fin:\rad+0.3)$) arc (\fin:\ini:\rad+0.3) -- cycle;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

%example of rainbow shading stolen from elsewhere
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow); 
 color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue); 
 color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shading=rainbow] 
  \shade[shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle +(3,1); 
 \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]
You can see that I made the arcs green, while I want them red-to-violet, or violet-to-red (if I specify the larger angle first, as in lines 3&4).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome! Where is `elsewhere`? Attribution is courteous, at the very least.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to use the rainbow shading, why do you say `fill=green`? Isn't it to be expected that you get a green filling in that case?

Comment: I guess you mean it is from the TikZ manual. That's not hard to acknowledge in your comment in the code, is it? Anyway, If you've read that, I guess you probably realise that this is not really supported by the shading facilities of TikZ/PGF. You could try to define a functional shading, I guess. (I could try, but I wouldn't succeed, so I won't.) If you aren't familiar with the PostScript or need something more reliable (e.g. will display, will print etc.), then I'd suggest defining a custom macro or a `pic` or something like that. It will be somewhat less flexible,, but more straightforward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you only require relatively short arc segments, I would suggest cheating and using a linear shading instead of trying to be correct. You could look up the definition of the `color wheel` shading in `pgflibraryshadings.code.tex` and try to modify it, but few PDF readers render it right.

I first tried to use the `shading angle` key to rotate the shading, but it seems to be broken in all but the simplest cases (I posted [a separate question on that subject](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300093/99343)). Instead, I now use the `transform canvas` option and leave the shading angle alone. This messes up the bounding box, however, so I tell TikZ to ignore the actual drawing and provide a dummy path instead.

Inverting the direction is done by conditonally rotating the path twice by 180 degrees, one time in a way that affects the shading, and one time in a way that doesn't. This is done if `\fin > \ini` using pgfmath's `?:` operator.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    %example of rainbow shading stolen from the pgf manual
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}{%
        color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
        color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
        color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);    % center c1
        \foreach \ini/\fin/\rad in {40 / 50/  3.0,
                                    120/160/  3.3,
                                    80 / 42/  3.6,  %backwards
                                    320/275/  3.9,  %backwards
                                    180/223/  4.2,
                                    265/285/  4.5,
                                    80/42/2} {
            \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
                \shade[shading=rainbow,rotate={\fin > \ini ? 0 : 180},transform canvas={rotate={(\fin + \ini) / 2 + (\fin > \ini ? 0 : 180)}}]
                    let \n1 = {(\fin - \ini) / 2} in
                        ($(c1) + (-\n1:\rad)$)
                    arc (-\n1:\n1:\rad)
                    --  ($(c1) + (\n1:\rad+0.3)$)
                    arc (\n1:-\n1:\rad+0.3)
                    -- cycle;
            \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \path
                    ($(c1) + (\ini:\rad)$)
                arc (\ini:\fin:\rad)
                --  ($(c1) + (\fin:\rad+0.3)$)
                arc (\fin:\ini:\rad+0.3)
                -- cycle;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: COOL!  Thanks - that's what I needed. I am impressed at the number of hurdles (linear shading: good hack; rotate shading broken; transform canvas !!! great idea; fixing bounding boxes). I am VERY IMPRESSED.

Comment: @amanzimdwini: I'm glad you like my solution :-). I didn't expect it to get anywhere as complicated as it did. It would help if you could mark this answer as accepted (check mark at the top left). This gives both of us some reputation and helps others recognize this question as solved.

Comment: @amanzimdwini Oh, you meant this? In that case, I didn't understand your question at all!