# Shading a tetrahedron in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to shade a tetrahedron in such a way, that the faces have a gradient with white being far away from the zero point of the coordinate system and being gray closer to the zero point of the coordinate system.

code so far

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(3cm,0)}, y={(0,3cm)}, z={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)}]
        \coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (A2) at (1,0,0);
        \coordinate (A3) at (0,1,0);
        \coordinate (A4) at (0,0,1);
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) node[below left] {$z$};
        \filldraw (1,0,0) circle (2pt);
        \filldraw (0,0,1) circle (2pt);
        \filldraw (0,1,0) circle (2pt);

        \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}
            \shadedraw[line width=0.3pt, opacity=0.2] (0.\x,0,0)--(0,0,0.\x);
        \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}
            \draw[line width=0.3pt, opacity=0.2] (0.\x,0,0)--(0,0.\x,0);
        \foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}
            \draw[line width=0.3pt, opacity=0.2] (0,0.\x,0)--(0,0,0.\x);

        \shadedraw[opacity=0.25, top color=white, bottom color=gray, shading angle=70] (A1)--(A3)--(A4) -- cycle;
        \shadedraw[opacity=0.25, top color=white, bottom color=gray, shading angle=190] (A1)--(A2)--(A4) -- cycle;
        \shadedraw[opacity=0.25, top color=white, bottom color=gray, shading angle=320] (A1)--(A2)--(A3) -- cycle;
        \shadedraw[opacity=0.4, outer color=white, inner color=gray] (A2)--(A3)--(A4) -- cycle;
        \draw (A2)--(A3)--(A4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is what it currently looks like]

This is what it currently looks like

EDIT: Any improvements on my foreach stuff highlighting depth is very welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the easiest shading, the `radial` shading with a center at the origin.

I've commented a path that creates the same shading but doesn't hide anything to show it works.

---

The second code shows “fake” shading since it just uses many filled areas that leave a thin triangular ring.

It might not be the most efficient approach but the easiest.

---

Using shadings in TikZ that covers a non-rectangular area at a specific angle (in 3d) isn't [very straight-forward.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680294)

But we can use the same technique as in the linked Q&A and declare our own shadings and guesstimate the needed values where the actual to-be-shaded part of the path inside its rectangular bounding box begins.

For this, I create a small command `\tikzdeclareverticalshading` that takes two arguments for the start and the end of the shading as well as the new shading's names.

Values less than 25 and greather than 75 shouldn't be used since this over-stretches the shading across the path's bounding box, though in this case, it seems to be a good approach visually. (The colors gray and white make me snow-blind the longer I stare at this example.)

If you use the `rectangle` path that's commented instead of the triangle you will see the exact path bounding box that the underlaying layer (usually PDF) uses to determine where and how the shading is applied. This might help with finding the right values for `\tikzdeclareverticalshading`.

### Code (radial shading)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(3cm,0)}, y={(0,3cm)}, z={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)}, line join=round]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) coordinate (x) at (1, 0, 0)
 coordinate (y) at (0, 1, 0) coordinate (z) at (0, 0, 1);

%\shadedraw[draw=red, inner color=blue, outer color=white]
%  ([xscale=-1]x|-y) rectangle ([yscale=-1]x|-y);
\shadedraw[inner color=gray, outer color=white] % shading = radial
  (x) -- (y) -- (z) -- cycle
  [overlay] ([rotate=180]y) ([rotate=180]x);
\foreach \v in {2, 4, 6, 8}
  \draw[line width=.3pt, gray]
    (0.\v, 0, 0) -- (0, 0.\v, 0) -- (0, 0, 0.\v) -- cycle;
\foreach \POS/\xyz in {right/x, above/y, below left/z} {
  \draw[->] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=1.2) node[\POS]{$\xyz$};
  \filldraw (xyz cs: \xyz=1) circle[radius=2pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (radial shading)

[image]

### Code (fake shading)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x={(3cm,0)}, y={(0,3cm)},
  z={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)},
  line join= round]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) coordinate (x) at (1, 0, 0)
 coordinate (y) at (0, 1, 0) coordinate (z) at (0, 0, 1);

\foreach[evaluate=\v as \col using 100-10*\v+10] \v in {10, 9.75, ..., 1}
  \fill[fill=gray!\col] (\v/10, 0, 0) -- (0, \v/10, 0) -- (0, 0, \v/10) -- cycle;

\foreach \v in {8, 6, 4, 2}
  \draw[gray, line width=.3pt] (.\v, 0, 0) -- (0, .\v, 0) -- (0, 0, .\v) -- cycle;
\draw (x) -- (y) -- (z) -- cycle;

\foreach \POS/\xyz in {right/x, above/y, below left/z} {
  \draw[->] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=1.2) node[\POS]{$\xyz$};
  \filldraw (xyz cs: \xyz=1) circle[radius=2pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (fake shading)

[image]

### Code (real shadings)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand*\tikzdeclareverticalshading[3]{%
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@bottom]{#3}{100bp}{%
    color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@top);color(#1bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
    color(#2bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom)}}
\tikzdeclareverticalshading{50}{85}{axis xy}
\tikzdeclareverticalshading{50}{70}{axis yz}
\tikzdeclareverticalshading{50}{70}{axis zx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(3cm,0)}, y={(0,3cm)}, z={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)}, line join=round]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) coordinate (x) at (1, 0, 0)
 coordinate (y) at (0, 1, 0) coordinate (z) at (0, 0, 1);

\foreach \xyz/\yzx/\ in {x/y, y/z, z/x}
  \shade[top color=white, bottom color=gray, shading=axis \xyz\yzx]
    let \p@=($(\yzx)-(\xyz)$) in [shading angle=-atan2(\p@)+90]
    (\xyz) -- (\yzx) -- (O) -- cycle;
%    (\xyz) rectangle (\yzx); % debug shading

\foreach \v in {8, 6, 4, 2}
  \draw[gray, line width=.3pt] (.\v, 0, 0) -- (0, .\v, 0) -- (0, 0, .\v) -- cycle;
\draw (x) -- (y) -- (z) -- cycle;

\foreach \POS/\xyz in {right/x, above/y, below left/z} {
  \draw[->] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=1.2) node[\POS]{$\xyz$};
  \filldraw (xyz cs: \xyz=1) circle[radius=2pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]