# How to rotate a gradient along with the rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, gradient

When I rotate a rectangle with a gradient fill, the gradient stays relative to the document or canvass or whatever. I want the gradient to rotate with the rectangle so that it changes along its width and not the diagonal.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (4); 
    \path (0,4) arc (90:-25:4cm) coordinate(mic);
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-25]
      \draw[bottom color = gray, top color = white, transform shape]  
           ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-0.25cm]mic) rectangle([xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.25cm]mic);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: Rectangle with diagonal gradient]

This has a gradient that goes from corner to corner because it hasn't rotated with the rectangle.

I know I can put the option [shading angle = ] in the draw command for the rectangle. But this seems to cause the gradient to still be applied over the vertical length of the rotated rectangle and then rotated, so that the gradient doesn't go from gray to white, but gray to a slightly lighter gray. I.e. the length of the gradient is greater than the width of the rectangle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the shading is applied to the whole bounding box of the rectangle in the paper coordinate system, see [Q300093](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300093), [Q680294](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680294), [Q682143](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682143).