# pgfdeclarehorizontalshading: Why are some color combinations resulting in no shading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, evince

The following displays no shading, it actually draws nothing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshade}{100bp}{%
    color(0bp)=(red);
    color(25bp)=(white);
    color(27bp)=(blue);
    color(40bp)=(white);
    color(100bp)=(white)}
  \shade[shading=myshade] (0, 0) rectangle (10, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But changing the last `white` to `red`, I obtain the correct shading.  Why is that?

**Edit:**  This may be a bug in `evince`.  Okular displays this properly.

Comment: Confirming: Okular 20.12.2 on Windows displays OK; so does Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Not sure because I should check it, but wasn't the really used shading the part between 25bp and 75bp?

Comment: Yes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300084/38080